# Access user BigQuery with com.google.api.services.bigquery or com.google.cloud.bigquery library

Tags: java, spring, google-bigquery

I have RESTfull backend application where I need to access users BigQuery tables. In order to do it, I want to use oAuth2, obtain accessToken and then use BQ SDK to manage users BQ tables. In playground I'm able to get an access-token (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) however I cant see any option to use on backend with SDK. Every authentication option demands p12 or PEM files. Is it any way to use oAuth token in mentioned libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Does https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2 help?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, it is. Please pop out your comment as an answer

Comment: Well it's really only "read the documentation" so far - not enough for an answer. It may be more useful if you self-answer, showing what code you ended up with.

Comment: I looked a lot of documentations but could not find this one.
I will post the code tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I am publishing an answer here with the "community wiki" tag, just for the sake that the community sees the question is now solved.

As answered by @JonSkeet in the comments, you can have more information about how to use OAuth2.0 with the Java Client Libraries in [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2).